# "Click" Event Not Firing for Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing some tests with `jest` and am not able to get a `click` event to fire.

Here's the first test, which works:

```
  it("should open drawer", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Header />);
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId("menuButton"));
    expect(getByTestId("drawer")).toBeVisible();
  });
```

The test successfully opens my "drawer" element with a click. The function works by removing the `visibility: hidden` style that's normally on this "drawer" element by default.

However, I'm having some trouble testing the "close" button, which adds that style back.

```
  it("should close drawer", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Header />);
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId("menuButton"));
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId("close"));
    expect(getByTestId("drawer")).not.toBeVisible(); // This doesn't work...
  });
```

The DOM (with `screen.debug`) doesn't seem to be picking up the second click. Logging the DOM shows that the styles not being applied. This happens despite the functionality working, for example withing Google Dev-Tools, using these functions:

```
// These both work....
$("button[data-testid='menuButton']").click()
$("button[data-testid='close']").click()
```

***What's going wrong? Why is the second click event not firing?***

Here's my full component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Drawer, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import Close from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import Menu from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import history from "../../history";

import Links from "./links";

import "./style.scss";

const Header = React.memo(function Header(props) {
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleGoHome = () => {
    history.push("/");
  };

  function handleDrawerToggle() {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  }

  return (
    <header className="header shadow">
      <nav>
        <IconButton
          data-testid="menuButton"
          onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
          className="menuButton pointer"
        >
          <Menu />
        </IconButton>
        <h1 onClick={handleGoHome} className="mainTitle pointer">
          Cloture
        </h1>
        <Drawer
          className="drawer"
          data-testid="drawer"
          anchor={"left"}
          open={mobileOpen}
          onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
        >
          <IconButton
            data-testid="close"
            className="close"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
          >
            <Close />
          </IconButton>
          <Links
            setMobileOpen={setMobileOpen}
            links={[
              { label: "Calendar", link: "/calendar" },
              { label: "Senate", link: "/committees/senate" },
              { label: "House", link: "/committees/house" },
            ]}
          />
        </Drawer>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
});

export default Header;
```

Comment: Does `@material-ui/core` animate the component with Javascript? Have you tried wrapping your `fireEvent.click` calls inside an `act(() => {} )`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [docs#waiting-for-disappearance](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance#waiting-for-disappearance), I think you will need to use the `waitForElementToBeRemoved()` async helper due to the animation that happens.

```
it("should close drawer", async () => {
  const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<Header />);

  fireEvent.click(getByTestId("menuButton"));
  expect(getByTestId("drawer")).toBeVisible();

  fireEvent.click(getByTestId("closeButton"));
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(getByTestId("drawer"));

  expect(queryByTestId("drawer")).toBeNull();

});
```

The `queryByTestId` is not needed, but just to show absolutely it has gone.

I have got a working example with your code here:

[image: Edit gracious-bardeen-jrwm1]

Comment: await waitForElementToBeRemoved() works!!! Thank you